# scoreboard that saves after sketch is restarted?- Processing

Tags: processing

Is there a way to create a scoreboard in processing that saves after the sketch is closed and reopened? And is there a way to make this work on android?

Comment: Don't know about android, but you can just use [saveStrings()](http://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html) and later [loadStrings()](http://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html)

Comment: How would I do that, I've never created a string in processing, and I need it to only show the one top score

Comment: Look at reference (linked) and try, If you get in trouble. Post your attempt and we can help.

Comment: Thanks man I'll get working on it :).  Edit-how do I make it work with an int such as highscore, rather than letters

Comment: You can convert it to strings for saving and back to int after read, or perhaps use [saveTable()](http://processing.org/reference/saveTable_.html). There are conversion functions in Processing API like [int()](http://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html) and [str()](http://processing.org/reference/strconvert_.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here a little sample using saveStrings():

```java
//random scores
int[] scores = {01,20,40,60,30,25};

void setup(){
  //convert and save
  String[] s = str(scores);
  saveStrings("sco.txt",s);

  //load in a different array...
  // the path to saved data, 
 String path = "/Users/vk/Documents/Processing/_forum/saveScore/sco.txt";
 int[] loadedScores = int(loadStrings(path));

 // ensure they are there...
 println(loadedScores);
}
```

Comment: As I said above, I now nothing about android mode... But I would guess that if you can write and read to a file, it should work...